# K1 visa - Consulate

Tags: italian-citizens, k1-visa

I am an Italian citizen but I live in the UK. I want to apply for a K1 visa.

Can I enter in the K1 forms an American **consulate located in the UK** (Edinburgh or London) **or am I obliged** to reference to an American consulate **in Italy**?

If the consulate in the UK is not feasible which US consulate in Italy deals with K1 visas, only the one in **Naples** or the one in **Milan** too?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply in the UK.  For example, see the USCIS page describing the process [step by step](https://www.uscis.gov/family/k-1-process-step-step) (emphasis added):

> USCIS sends the approved petition to the DOS National Visa Center (NVC), which forwards it to the embassy or consulate where the foreign fiancé/fiancée will apply for the K-1 visa (generally, the embassy or consulate in the area **where the person lives**).

Comment: Yep, makes sense after all. If for instance I was living in Australia and getting married in USA it would made no sense to have to fly to Italy just for an interview. Thanks